How do I migrate this MVVM approach in WPF to WinUI?
Historically in WPF when using MVVM (typically done with MVVMLight) I use the approach where I bind a control to something in its view-model. To wit:
XAML:
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:My.Namespace.ViewModels"

And then declare the data context in XAML using
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"

ViewModel:
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   // Properties, methods, commands etc. here
}

MVVMLight kicked in and provides the ViewModel locator which allowed me to do the following in the App.xaml
<local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="locator"/>

local is defined earlier in the XAML similar to how
My questions are:

What's the way to follow this kind of pattern now with MVVM Toolkit? The Migrating from MvvmLight article glossed over it. All the examples provided are far too complex for what I'm looking for.

Setting a whole Window's Data Context now appears impossible. Do I need to use the x:Bind syntax for each control?

As an extension of 2. above the examples I've seen are all setting the Data Context within the code-behind. Is this now the recommended approach?


I got this approach years ago mainly from reading Josh Smith's website and some of the  Reed Copsey's excellent answers on this site like: What is the preferred way to connect viewmodels to their views?

x:Bind does not use DataContext as its source. Let me show you a simple sample code using the CommunitToolkit.Mvvm.
MainPage.xaml
<Page
    x:Class="CommunityToolkitMvvmDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:CommunityToolkitMvvmDemo"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox
            PlaceholderText="Enter..."
            Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <!--  x:Bind is `OneTime` mode by default.  -->
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomeText, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Button
            Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClearSomeTextCommand}"
            Content="Clear" />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>

MainPage.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}

MainPageViewModel.cs
// This class needs to be `partial` for the source generator.
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // The source generator will create a `SomeText` property for you.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _someText = string.Empty;

    // The source generator will create a `ClearSomeTextCommand` for you.
    [RelayCommand]
    private void ClearSomeText() => SomeText = string.Empty;
}

As you can see, instead of using the DataContext, I have a MainPageViewModel property initialized in code-behind.
If you want to inject the ViewModel, you can just:
public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewModel)
{
    ViewModel = viewModel;
    InitializeComponent();
}

Just so you know, you can still use Binding just like WPF:
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox
        PlaceholderText="Enter..."
        Text="{Binding SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
    <Button
        Command="{Binding ClearSomeTextCommand}"
        Content="Clear" />
</StackPanel>

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }

but you should use x:Bind whenever you can for performance and compile-time validation reasons.
UPDATE
If you want to set the DataContext in XAML, you can:
<Page...>

    <Page.DataContext>
       <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
   </Page.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox
            PlaceholderText="Enter..."
            Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomeText, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Button
            Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClearSomeTextCommand}"
            Content="Clear" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>


Thanks! I got more out of this answer than all of the documentation I've read. To be clear, there is now no way to set the DataContext from XAML any more? Also, you're using Page instead of Window - are your examples MAUI?

In WinUI 3, the Window class is not a DependencyObject and this made the Window class very limited with some features.

So, usually you just use it as a wrapper and place a Page as its content.

@noonand you can set the DataContext on other elements, just not the Window. You can still set it on a root Grid for example. But be warned - Microsoft botched dynamic binding when they first made Metro so it's on the order of 10x slower than WPF. The whole reason they introduced x:Bind - and eliminated many important features like MultiBinding and RelativeSource binding - was to try to push you to use compile-time binding. So if you can use x:Bind you will get better performance.

That's fine @EmperorEto thanks for that. Now that I have a way of doing it from the XAML I have no issue. It just felt like a retrograde step to have to go back to naming controls and setting their properties from code-behind again. Added to that MVVM Light was gone and I really needed a canonical reference like above.
